# Azure Function App not able to access Azure SQL server- saying Client IP need to be added in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server, azure-function-app

Getting below exception when my Azure Function App tries to connect with Azure SQL Server.

```
Cannot open server 'my-sql-sever' requested by the login. Client with IP address '52.165.228.212' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
```

Getting below exception when my Azure Function App tries to connect with Azure SQL Server.

Cannot open server 'my-sql-sever' requested by the login. Client with IP address '52.165.228.212' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
I was in impression that by default all Azure IPs of SQL database are whitelisted to Azure Fuction.

Please suggest.

Thanks, 
Siraj

Comment: As the error mentioned, you need to add IP address '52.165.228.212' to your firewall of SQL server.

Comment: I have the same error, but the IP address changes everytime the function is executed. @NancyXiong

Answer (score 4):

You can either configure your SQL to [allow connections from inside Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure) or you have to create a firewall rule for the Azure Function IP address (see [Create and manage IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure))

Answer (score 1):

We need to white list the our function app hosted IP address. This can be fund the configuration settings. This is typically a range.